# show background image in sectionIndexTitles method of UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to create a border in `UITableViewSection` title background [check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rD7aV.png)

I want to make background like ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ show in image and want to create header as well.

Comment: What header. Does image you shared, depicts final out come?

Comment: yes in image at right side you see ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ they contain one background rounded that I have to made